# Padrão de projeto para retorno de API C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, exceção

Tenho uma API em C# (.NET), em 5 camadas.

Service.Api - Porta de entrada, onde ficam os controllers
Service.Business - Camada de negócios, toda regra fica aqui
Service.Entities - Models (Entities), Requests e Responses
Service.Persistence - Camada de conexão ao banco de dados
Service.Tests - Teste da aplicação

A requisição chega na Controller (Service.Api), e o controller chama a Business, para realizar as operações.

A dúvida é:
Tenho uma tabela de cidades. O cara pediu pra cadastrar uma cidade com nome que já existe na base, qual a forma correta, lançar uma exception, ou devolver de algum forma isso pra controller e a controller cuidar disso?

```
var cityExists = _context.Cities.Where(x => x.Name == request.Name);

if (cityExists != null) {
     throw new ArgumentException("Cidade já existente!");
}

// RESTO DO CÓDIGO
```

Por padrões de projeto, o que seria o correto?
Já li conteúdos que dizem que não faz sentido usar exceções para controlar o fluxo de execução.
Como lidar com isso nesse caso? Há algum padrão ou consenso da comunidade?

Obrigado!

Comment: [Relacionada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control)

Comment: Não consigo que seja relacionada, já que no post citado não houve nenhum proposta de solução.
Dizem para não usar, mas não dizem sobre o melhor caminho a seguir.

Answer (score -4):

Quando falamos de API a ideia é que o retorno seja padronizado, usando os código de status de resposta do http. No .NET podemos retornar uma interface chamada [IActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-7.0), no seu caso em especifico, tem dois retornos que se encaixariam para essa situação você pode retorna um dos dois código de status de resposta:

400 Bad Request: significa que o servidor não processará a solicitação devido a algo que é percebido como um erro do cliente (por exemplo, sintaxe de solicitação malformada,enquadramento de mensagem de solicitação inválido ou roteamento de solicitação enganoso).

409 Conflict: A solicitação não pôde ser concluída devido a um conflito com o atual estado do recurso. Este código só é permitido em situações onde
espera-se que o usuário consiga resolver o conflito
e reenvie a solicitação. O corpo da resposta DEVE incluir o suficiente informações para o usuário reconhecer a origem do conflito.

Você pode colocar mensagem na resposta do retorno, a ideia é que seu código fique mais ou menos assim:

1º Adicione o using ao seu codigo

```
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
```

2º O seu metodo deve ficar parecido:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AdicionaCidade([FromBody] City city)
{
var cityExists = _context.Cities.Where(x => x.Name == request.Name);

if (cityExists != null)
{
    return Conflict("Cidade já cadastrada");
}
_context.Cities.Add(city);
_context.SaveChanges();
//por padrão quando se cria algo esse é o retorno padrão vc devolve um 201 create e o objeto que foi inserido
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(RecuperaCidadePorID), new { id = city.id }, city);
}
```